# PHPExcel function showing error on php version 8

Tags: php, phpexcel-1.8.0

I upgrading my website from php 5.6 to php 8 , i am working on changing the PHPexcel to run in php 8 but getting below issue any idea to fix it

```
try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel   = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
            
            
            $worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($inputFileName);
```

these below lines working and returning valid response

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel   = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

Comment: I can't see the "_below issue_" following those words.. and if I correctly understand what you meant later, is the very last statement (`->listWorksheetInfo()`) the only one generating the unexpected result? ...if so, what's exactly the issue? I ask because I used phpexcel only with php5.4 so far.

Comment: the same thing working in php 5 , i just upgraded version to php 8 with same code in another server,i am getting this message Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Reader_HTML::listWorksheetInfo() ,

Comment: i also replaced curly braces in PHPexcel classes {} [] because of PHP 8